# How to connect to a webserver from a remote pc through ip address using websocket

Tags: php, websocket

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/) to create a Websocket chat example with PHP.

It works well on localhost but when I try to connect the server from another computer it does not connect. I tried changing the start server IP to my LAN ipv4 address but it did not work. When I tried to use my external IP, the server did not start with the error:

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10049]: The requested address is not valid in its context.

Is there any way to connect from another client to the server running in my LAN IP address or external IP address?

Comment: server.php - work fine? Not have errors? Maybe it is die after start? If you have linux try in sh: ps aux | grep server.php

Comment: @MaximTkach I used my WLAN ipv4 address, not 127.0.0.1. On the other computer 127.0.0.1 connects to its own localhost so it cannot connect to my server. I tried 0.0.0.0, but it gives: " WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.0.0:9300/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID" error so I cannot even start the server on my computer.

Comment: @MaximTkach I can send and retrieve messages on the same browser, different browsers and even on the virtual machine with ubuntu with my host OS Windows. So I think server.php works fine.

Comment: If the other computer is not on your LAN, then you will need to both use the public IP address and you will need to configure your router to port forward the public IP address on the desired port to the private IP address of your computer on your LAN.  The public IP address belongs to the router, not to your computer so you need to get it to send that traffic to your computer.  If the other computer is on your LAN, then you can just use the private IP address of the destination computer on your LAN.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 - need write to socket_bind (in server.php) connect ust be you LAN address